# Which jar I need to download during upgrading JIRA?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jira

While upgrading jira version I met this error in my console.

So please tell me which jar I need to install to overcome this error?

If you encounter issues starting or stopping JIRA, please see the Troubleshooting.

```
Using JIRA_HOME:        D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\JIRA\atlassian-jira-6.0-m08-standalone\bin\bootst
```

The error:

```
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.setRulesValidation(Z)**
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.createStartDigester(Catalina
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorI
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodA
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download following jar

tomcat-util.jar

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can add the tomcat-util-[Latest Version].jar
Also for your reference if you face similar issues, and trying to figure out which jar is required, you can have a look at [FindJar website](http://www.findjar.com)

Hope that helps in future.